# In Python, How to remove various unwanted quotes in a string to create/convert to a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace, double-quotes

I have a string in the following form:

```
testline = "{""key1"": ""value1"", ""key2"": {""value2-subkey1"": ""value2-subvalue2""}}"
```

I would like to replace the double-double quotes with a single-double quote (") and strip the initial and final double quote to finish with a dictionary.

So far, I've got something like this, which is very much not doing what I want.

```
import ast
# testline = testline.strip(")
testline = testline.replace('""', '"')
testlinedict = ast.literal_eval(testline)
```

This so far yields `ValueError: malformed string`

I want the final result to be:

```
testlinedict = {"key1": "value1", "key2": {"value2-subkey1": "value2-subvalue2"}}
```

Comment: this sounds like you want to use `eval` - since you have unwanted "" in your data, you probably don't have enought control over the data and it would be huge security risk :(

Comment: `.strip()` can remove characters from the string only, first and last quotes are not part of the string literal !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the double quotes are actually interpreted by Python, but not in the way you expected:

```
>>> testline = "{""key1"": ""value1"", ""key2"": {""value2-subkey1"": ""value2-subvalue2""}}"
>>> testline
'{key1: value1, key2: {value2-subkey1: value2-subvalue2}}'
```

This is because in Python, like in C, several string literals following each other are interpreted as one large string, so `"abc""def" == "abcdef"`.

If you define `testdata` correctly, your solution works:

```
>>> testline = '{""key1"": ""value1"", ""key2"": {""value2-subkey1"": ""value2-subvalue2""}}'
>>> literal_eval(testline.replace('""', '"'))
{'key2': {'value2-subkey1': 'value2-subvalue2'}, 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Or, in case the first and last quote are actually part of the string:

```
>>> testline = '"{""key1"": ""value1"", ""key2"": {""value2-subkey1"": ""value2-subvalue2""}}"'
>>> literal_eval(testline[1:-1].replace('""', '"'))
{'key2': {'value2-subkey1': 'value2-subvalue2'}, 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: @Wayne Werner, don't worry, he beat me by 14 minutes ;-)

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I completely didn't understand the interpretation by Python. That explains a lot of problems of mine... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
testline=testline.replace("\"\"","\"")[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testline = testline.replace('""', '"')
testline = testline[1:-1]
```

Replace the doubled doublequotes first, then just take off the first and last characters to remove the leading and trailing doublequotes.

If you actually want to wind up with a dictionary object, rather than a string representation of one, you should then use something like `ast.literal_eval()` to load the string as Python code (or `json.loads()` to load it as JSON).

Comment: I think the OP wants something like `ast.literal_eval()` or `json.loads()` to build a dictionary from the string.

Comment: Quite possibly. In which case, they can use one of those to load the resulting string.

Comment: why `testline[1:-1]`? it would remove `{` and `}` from the string literal `"{...}"`

Comment: @deathApril I'm operating under the assumption that there are single doublequote characters at the beginning and end of the string literal due to what the OP typed, given that `"{""key""...` wouldn't be a valid string literal as-is. If that's not the case, the `testline[1:-1]` part can be removed.

Comment: If I use `testline = testline.replace('""', '"')` followed by `testline = ast.literal_eval(testline)` (NOT removing the braces with `testline = testline[1:-1]`), I receive a `ValueError: malformed string`.

Comment: @Amber @Sven-Marnach `testlinedict = json.loads(testline)` produces the following error: `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)`

Comment: I'd suggest trying just `print(testline)` and seeing what the actual result is before you try to load it. See what's wrong there.